# Grouping vectors together

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $0 \leq u\cdot v<1$ for all pair of distinct vectors $u,v$. These vectors span a $d$-dimensional subspace s.t. $d< n$. We conjecture that it is possible to partition the $n$ vectors into $d$ groups such that all the vectors within the same group are pairwise non-orthogonal. It trivially holds when $d\in\{1,2,n-1,n-2\}$. However, we have not been able to show for general $d$. Does the conjecture hold for any $d< n$? If yes, how to prove it? Any thoughts/hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "mutually non-orthogonal" do you mean "pairwise non-orthogonal"
for the vectors in the $d$ sets, or do you mean that no vector in the set is orthogonal to ALL of the others?

Comment: I mean pairwise non-orthogonal. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your question is very related to Borsuk's conjecture, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%27s_conjecture
(I am sure you know it, but want to say just in case not.) 

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I must admit that I was not aware of it. 

Comment: The statement is of course true for $d=n$. It seems more elegant to include that case.

Comment: Since Borsuk's conjecture is proven false, the question is if doing things for very large convex bodies on the surface of a sphere makes it harder or easier. If you take antipodal points, it gets much easier, but that's not very convincing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kahn--Kalai's [counterexample to Borsuk's conjecture](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.MG/9307229) is a collection of vertices of the unit cube.

Imagine that this cube sits in a coordinate hyperplane $x_1=s$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, so that the origin projects to the center of the cube.
Project this cube centrally to the unit sphere.
For a right choice of $s$, you get a counterexample to your statement.